# How Implement Thread Within Another Thread in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

Scenario: There is One Requests And Many Suppliers,So for getting Results From all Suppliers I use,

```
var supplierResults = suppliers.AsParallel()
                           .WithDegreeOfParallelism(suppliers.Count())
                           .Select(supplier => supplier.GetResponse(request, SuppliersRequestTimespan))
                           .ToArray(); 

                    Task.WaitAll(supplierResults);
```

Which is Working Fine.

In Another Scenario, I have Three Different Requests and Want to send it to all Suppliers Simultaneously(threads).I Just Tried Like Below:

```
int TaskCount = 3;
var tasks = new Task[TaskCount];

tasks[0] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => (suppliers.AsParallel()
                                            .WithDegreeOfParallelism(suppliers.Count())
                                            .Select(supplier => supplier.GetResponse(request1, SuppliersRequestTimespan))
                                            .ToArray()));
tasks[1] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => (suppliers.AsParallel()
                                                .WithDegreeOfParallelism(suppliers.Count())
                                                .Select(supplier => supplier.GetResponse(request2, SuppliersRequestTimespan))
                                                .ToArray()));
 tasks[2] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => (suppliers.AsParallel()
                                                .WithDegreeOfParallelism(suppliers.Count())
                                                .Select(supplier => supplier.GetResponse(request3, SuppliersRequestTimespan))
                                                .ToArray()));

 Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

But,Unfortunately It Not 'Wait for' the Response.

`GetResponse()` Method is From an Interface as showing Below:

```
 public interface ISupplier
    {
        Task<JObject> GetResponse(JObject request, TimeSpan timeout);

        Task<JObject> GetResponseAsync(JObject request, TimeSpan timeout);
        string GetSupplierBrand();
        string GetSupplierCulture();
    }
```

Hope You guys Help me to complete this..

Comment: Is supplier.GetResponse() method Asynchronous? That is causing your control to return without all actual tasks being complete. Also, the .ToArray() seems to be at odd location. check why you cant have it like the one which worked.

Comment: @HenkHolterman `GetResponse()` is  from an Interface as Shown Above.

Comment: You should really use Microsoft's Reactive Framework for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Microsoft's Reactive Framework for this.

Here's the main code:

```
var requests = new[] { request1, request2, request3 };

var query =
    from supplier in suppliers.ToObservable()
    from request in requests.ToObservable()
    from response in Observable.FromAsync(() =>
        supplier.GetResponseAsync(request, SuppliersRequestTimespan))
    select new { supplier, request, response };
```

Now, if you want to get all of the results as an array just call this:

```
var results = query.ToArray().Wait();
```

But you can always use the Reactive Framework to get each result as soon as they come in. Just do this:

```
var subscription =
    query
        .Subscribe(result =>
        {
            // Do something with each result
        });
```

All of this is multi-threaded and uses the maximum number of available threads.

It's almost too simple.